# Linq ordering output

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to sort a listbox by the `customerID` and then by `Total (discount*unitPrice*quantity`)  and cannot manage to organize the code in a way that will sort it in that way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**[HERE](http://postimg.org/image/6t9paiyw3/)** is a link showing an image on how the results should be returned as.

```
var load1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\AS3Products.csv")
            .Select(x => new
            {
                CID = x.Split(',')[0],
                discount = x.Split(',')[2].Trim(),
                productId = x.Split(',')[0].Trim()
            });

var load2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\AS3Transactions.csv")
            .Select(x => new
            {
                productId = x.Split(',')[3],
                unitPrice = x.Split(',')[4],
                quantity = x.Split(',')[5]
            });

var querypractice = from x in load1
                    join y in load2 on x.productId equals y.productId 
                    where x.CID == "110"
                    orderby x.discount, y.quantity
                    select new { x.CID, x.discount, x.productId, y.quantity, y.unitPrice };

foreach (var x in querypractice)
{
    double total = double.Parse(x.quantity) * double.Parse(x.unitPrice) * double.Parse(x.discount);
    listBox1.Items.Add(x.CID+ "   " +x.discount+"   "+x.quantity+ "   " + total);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement a custom `IComparer<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't have VS on this machine, so this isn't validated, but I think you can do it using the LET statement to set up the calculated value, then order based on it.

```
var querypractice = from x in load1
                join y in load2 on x.productId equals y.productId 
                let total = x.discount*x.unitPrice*x.quantity
                where x.CID == "110"
                orderby x.CID, total
                select new { x.CID, total };
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231164/Into-and-let-in-LINQ-Let-vs-Into

Comment: Thank you, that is the exact code I've been trying to figure out, using `let` for creating the total is the exact information that i needed.

Comment: Great - if this worked then please mark as the right answer, or let me know any compilation issues and i'll update the answer.

Comment: See Grant's answer below - I forgot to cast the items as numeric types. You'll need to do that in order to use the * operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you're *positive* that these files have numbers in the expected places all the time, you could parse them as you read them from the files. Otherwise, you'll want to do some validation first or you'll get exceptions.

*(I changed* `double.Parse` *to* `decimal.Parse` *- [it's more accurate for manipulating dollar amounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c).)*

```
 var load1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\AS3Products.csv")
 .Select(x => new
 {
     CID = int.Parse(x.Split(',')[0]),
     discount = decimal.Parse(x.Split(',')[2].Trim()),
     productId = int.Parse(x.Split(',')[0].Trim())
 });

 var load2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\AS3Transactions.csv")
             .Select(x => new
             {
                 productId = int.Parse(x.Split(',')[3]),
                 unitPrice = decimal.Parse(x.Split(',')[4]),
                 quantity = int.Parse(x.Split(',')[5])
             });
```

Then you can create your list like this. *(I removed the specific id you had in your query.)*

```
 var orderedList = (from x in load1
                    join y in load2 on x.productId equals y.productId
                    let total = (x.discount * y.unitPrice * y.quantity)
                    orderby x.CID descending, total descending
                    select new
                    {
                        x.CID,
                        x.discount,
                        x.productId,
                        y.quantity,
                        y.unitPrice
                    });
```